# how to import package from github

Tags: go

I'm trying to build a api using Go and I tried running a existing file from GitHub that I got from udemy course. I'm getting this kind of output:

```
C:\goworkspace\src\grpc-go-course-master\blog\blog_client>go run client.go
client.go:4:2: cannot find package "context" in any of:
        C:\go\src\context (from $GOROOT)
        C:\goworkspace\src\context (from $GOPATH)
..\..\..\golang.org\x\net\http2\not_go111.go:10:2: cannot find package "net/http/httptrace" in any of:
        C:\go\src\net\http\httptrace (from $GOROOT)
        C:\goworkspace\src\net\http\httptrace (from $GOPATH)
```

Could you suggest me what can cause this error?

Comment: You Go installation is broken or far too old.

Comment: Which version of Go are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to download the dependencies, you have to use the `go get` command:

```sh
go get -v -u github.com/alessiosavi/GoUtils
```

Change with the package that you need (in that repo you can find a bunch of 'utils' method).

If the project, instead, have the `go.mod` file, you have to type:

```sh
go clean
go build
```

By this way you are going to install the dependencies listed in the `go.mod` file.

For update the dependencies to the latest version:

```sh
go get -v -u all
```

Answer (score 0):

```
go mod tidy
```

The above command looks for missing dependencies, adds them to `go.mod`, and installs them.